# How to find all orthogonal coordinates in a space of dimension $n$

Tags: differential-equations

I have been thinking for a while how to determine all the orthogonal coordinate systems in linear spaces of an arbitrary dimension $n$.

The motivation for such a task comes from physics: I am studying a separability of Hamilton-Jacobi equations in "some orthogonal systems". The merit is to examine how does an orthogonality relate to the separation in general.

Let $n$ be a natural and suppose $\mathbf{q}=(q^1, q^2, ..., q^n)$ are coordinates describing $\mathbb{R}^n$. The coordinates are orthogonal if and only if the coordinate surfaces all meet at right angles. This means that while setting for each $i \in \{1,2, ..., n\}$ $q^i = const$ the hyperplanes obtained all meet at right angles.

For example in $\mathbb{R}^n$ the cartesian coordinates are orthogonal. Surely, we can describe $\mathbb{R}^n$ using generalized spherical coordinates etc.

I tried to figure out how to find "all" the orthogonal coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We can obtain some of them trivially from those we already know using rotations, shrinking and in general any orthogonal linear transformations. But how to find the coordinates which couldn't be obtained like that?

I had a look at the transformations from a cartesian set of coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$ $\mathbf{x}=(x^1, x^2, ..., x^n)$ which preserves the orthogonality. Let $f$ be a transformation of the coordinate system $\mathbf{x}$ to a new one, say $\mathbf{y}=(y^1, y^2, ..., y^n)$. We would like f to be regular and defined at domain of f $\mathrm{dom}(f)=\mathbb{R}^n \setminus M$, where the set $M$ has Lebesgue measure zero. Locally, the orthogonality condition requires that the linear approximation of vectors $y^i$ where $i \in \{1,2, ..., n\}$ created an orthogonal set. The linear approximation of $y^i$ at an arbitrary fixed point $\mathbf{x_0}$ is it's derivative at $\mathbf{x_0}$ $(y^i)'(\mathbf{x_0})$ . (Here the derivative of a mapping r from a Banach space E to a Banach space F at a point t is understood as a linear mapping r'(t) which is tangent to r.) This means: for each par of $i, j \in \{1,2, ..., n\}$ and each point $\mathbf{x} \in \mathrm{dom}(f)$ the dot product of $(y^i)'(\mathbf{x}) \cdot (y^j)'(\mathbf{x})$ equals zero for $i \neq j$ and equals a positive number otherwise.

In the notation of Jacobian matrices: $J_f$ of $f$: $(J_f)^TJ_f=A$, where $A$ is a diagonal matrix. This should be true in a more general case when f is considered to be a mapping of an arbitrary orthonormal coordinate system to a new orthogonal system.

This method gives a system of nonlinear PDE's which is quite unsolvable. (Or at least it seems to me.)

Do you have any other idea how to find orthogonal systems describing linear spaces? Do you know about an interesting book covering the topic of orthogonal systems deeper then giving a list of the known ones in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$. I would like to get some insight in separation of differential equations also, so I appreciate tips for articles covering this subject too.

Thanks a lot, Filip.

PS: This is my first question here. I am not sure whether I posted it right.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^2$, pick an arbitrary smooth function $q^1$. Then define level sets of $q^2$ using flow along normal directions of $q^1$. You get lots, and lots of examples this way.

Answer (score 5):

This problem was studied, and expressed as an integrable PDE system, by Zakharov, [Description of the $n$-Orthogonal Curvilinear
Coordinate Systems and Hamiltonian Integrable Systems of Hydrodynamic Type.
Part 1. Integration of the Lam ́e Equations.](http://math.arizona.edu/~zakharov/2Articles/ORTHO.pdf)

The problem was also the subject of a book of Darboux, **Leçons
 sur
 les
 Systèmes
  Orthogonaux
 et
 les
  Coordonnées
  Curvilignes**, but this was long before the methods that Zakharov used were available, so it might be better to start with Zakharov's paper.